# Is every digit sequence contained in a multiple of any other natural number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

Given a pair of integers, $m$ and $n$, is there some $k$ such that $m$ is embedded somewhere in the digits of $ kn $?

By embedded, I mean $m$'s ordered digit sequence is a substring of $kn$. As an example, for $n=1,234$ and $k=1$, the following values of $m$ are embedded in $kn$:  $$ m \in \{1,2,3,4,12,23,34,123,234,1234\} $$ If $k=10$, $kn=12,340 $ and possible values of $m$ are $$m \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, \mathbf{0}, 12, 23, 34, \mathbf{40}, 123,234,\mathbf{340},1234,\mathbf{2340}, \mathbf{12340}\}$$

If I would like $37$ to be a possible value for $m$ when $n=1,234$ I need only set $k=3$, giving $kn=3,702$ and possible values for $m$ as $$m \in \{3, 7, 0, 2, \mathbf{37}, 70, 370, 702, 3702\}$$

Is there a proof that shows that any $m$ can be found as a substring of some multiple of any $n$? If so, what is the method for finding the smallest value for $k$ that satisfies the embedding requirement, given some pair $(m,n)$?

**Note:** There may be a better term for "embedded" of which I am unaware. Additionally, I'm not entirely sure under which tags to post this, so if there are other tags it that should be included, I'll make updates.

Comment: Note standard notation: $m \in \{ 1, 2, 3\}$ etc.  I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Sure....pick some huge number $t$ (much larger than either $m,n$) and look at $\alpha= 10^tm$  then there is some multiple of $n$ contained in $\{\alpha ,\alpha +1,\cdots,\alpha+(n-1)\}$ and all of those contain $m$ as the first few digits.

Note:  as pointed out in the comments below, taking $t$ to be the length of $n-1$ suffices (so it doesn't have to be all that big).

Comment: Why huge? It just has to be greater than $\log_{10}(n - 1)$.

Comment: @shardulc  True, I was being lazy.  I'll edit accordingly, thanks!

Comment: This proves that there exists some $k$ that satisfies the embedding criteria, but it doesn't necessarily give the smallest value for $k$. With the example of $m=37$ and $n=1234$ given above, we get $k=300$ using this method. Is there a way to determine the smallest value of $k$, which we know to be $3$?

Comment: @PaulCauchon  You are correct...I get an upper bound, but almost certainly not a very good one.  I played with trying to improve on that but didn't come up with anything very useful.  Randomly selected examples make the thing look fairly chaotic, but sometimes useful patterns escape quick detection.

Comment: @PaulCauchon  If you want to follow up on this, I'd say the first question was "fixing a length $L$ and integer $m$, is there always a number $n$ such that $n-1$ has length $L$ and for which my construction is optimal?"  I did not look at this at all...but it should be easy to check (via computer) for modest $L$.  Might be interesting.  All yours, if you care to follow up.